# How to restore instance using snapshot in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I created a snapshot of a VM instance via cloud console. I would like to know how I can restore an instance using a snapshot. The documentation for compute engine is not very helpful. The instance runs on Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

To restore an instance from a snapshot without deleting/re-creating the instance:

1. Shut down the instance and detach the boot disk: `gcloud beta compute instances detach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk BOOT_DISK_NAME`
2. Create a new disk from the snapshot: `gcloud compute disks create DISK_NAME --source-snapshot SNAPSHOT_NAME`
3. Attach the disk created from step 2 as the boot disk: `gcloud beta compute instances attach-disk INSTANCE_NAME --disk DISK_NAME --boot`

Restoring the instance without deleting/re-creating the instance means that after restore, the instance will keep its IP address and other properties like tags, labels, etc.

Comment: consider delete the old disk if you want the new disk to have the same name

Comment: This is unbelievable that this is the way to restore the snapshot on the machine, I feel like I have to be doing something wrong. This can't be the right solution to such simple task as snapshot restore.

Comment: These three commands were enormously useful to me tonight. A thousand times, thank you.

Comment: Thank you! :) Stack Overflow > GCP documentation :D

Comment: There is a way to do this with a Persistent disk snapshot?

Answer (score 5):

In Console, you can go to VM Instances from Compute Engine tab.
There you click on '+Create Instance'
and there in section of boot-disk, you can navigate to 'snapshots' tab and select the snapshot you took.

Like this from console, you can Restore your instance.

Let me know, if this doesn't work for you!

Answer (score 4):

Try using:

```
gcloud compute disks \
create <NEW_INSTANCE_NAME> \
--source-snapshot <SNAPSHOT_NAME> \
--type pd-ssd \
--zone <ZONE>
```

You could find useful instruction [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpo200-snapshots/#4).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in the web interface, it's pretty easy. Edit your VM instance.  Scroll down to your boot disk and click "x" next to the boot volume, then click create button.  In the next window give your new volume a meaningful name, set up your snapshot schedule, and then under "source type" select "Snapshot".  Choose your snapshot from the dropdown.  If you have a customer managed/supplied key (not recommended) select it, otherwise leave it as google-managed key.   Click create.  Depending on disk size it might take a while.  Be patient and let it finish the setup and then start your instance once it is al complete.