# Unable to access google cloud instance in browser window(We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud instance and i was able to access the instance properly. But unfortunately i made some changes in the “/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0” file and after that i am not able to access that instance. I tried all most all methods to access the instance.But there is no luck.

If any body have any idea please share it. Thanks in advance

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42476941/how-to-restore-instance-using-snapshot-in-google-compute-engine ...while the serial console would also permit to bring IF `eth0` back up.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this method? [Using serial console to interact with your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole).

Answer (score 0):

If you can’t find anything useful by using the [Serial Console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole). Then the best and useful approach is to create a snapshot with the failed instance and create a new one using the previous snapshot:

1. Go to Compute Engine section.
2. Then select “Snapshots” in the left menu.
3. Click “Create Snapshot”.
4. In “source disk” select your current VM instance, Encryption: automatic and provide the required information in the other fields.
5. Click “Create”.

After the snapshot is created then you can go and use it to create a new VM, in the “Create instance” section do the following:

1. In “Boot Disk” click the “Change” button.
2. Click the “Snapshots” tab (upper right).
3. Select the previously created snapshot.
4. Click “select” and then “Create”.

You should be able to SSH into the new instance. If you want to keep the IP from the “old” instance, then you can configure its IP as [static](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static), delete (or stop) the old instance and then [assign the static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#IP_assign) to the previously created VM instance.

Answer (score 0):

After reading so many forums of google cloud and other site i found one solution. Below is the solution from google cloud support team.

1- If you made any changes in the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 its too dificult to access the instance over browser console or serial console.

In the above scenario follow the below steps to recover the data from the instance
Asume your old instance is “instance-1”

Created a new instance named “instance-2”

1) Go to the instance details of “instance-1” click the “EDIT” button and uncheck the “Delete boot disk when instance is deleted” option, this step is very important otherwise you will be losing your data.

2) Delete your instance “instance-1” your disk will be kept, hence your data.

3) On Cloud Shell attach your disk “instance-1” to the new instance by running: gcloud compute instances attach-disk  --disk  --zone

4) SSH to your new instance and create a directory that servers as the mount point for your disk by running: sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]

5) On your new instance session mount the disk to the instance by running: sudo mount -o discard,defaults /dev/[DEVICE_ID] /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]

6) On your new instance session configure read and write permissions on the device by running: sudo chmod a+w /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR]

Notes:  Replace  with instance-1 and  with the instance that you create (instance-2), remember that the zone of your new instance must match with the zone of your “ instance-1” disk. Replace [MNT_DIR] with any name that you want to give to the directory, you can get the [DEVICE_ID] by running “lsblk” on your new instance once the disk is attached, the id is normally sdb1. You can refer to this document [1] in the section “Formatting and mounting a persistent disk” however, please avoid step number four (the command mkfs.ext4) since this would delete your data.

After you have performed all the steps you should be able to use “cd” to go to /mnt/disks/[MNT_DIR] and look for your files there.